# Проблема с добавлением модулей qt в qbs

Tags: qt, qmake, qbs

1. Есть Linux-машина на которой настроена кросс-компиляция для Raspberry Pi.
2. В какой то момент потребовалось добавить модуль Qt.charts
3. Модуль скомпилирован и проект с использованием qmake замечательно его видит и все работает как и ожидается
4. Однако проект на qbs выдает сообщение об ошибке

> Dependency 'Qt.charts' not found for product 'cu-tempmeasurer'.

5. Как побороть эту проблему?

Код из qbs-файла:

```
    Depends {
       name: "Qt";
       submodules: [
           "core",
           "gui",
           "network",
           "serialport",
           "widgets",
           "printsupport",
           "charts"
       ]
    }
```